# How to automatically update the backgound color of a cell, based on the the background color of a cell in a different sheet?

Tags: macros, libreoffice, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

I'm creating a template in LibreOffice Calc. If the background color of a cell in a specific range of the first sheet is changed, I want the background color of the corresponding cell on the second sheet to update to the same color. How should I set up my template to achieve this behavior?

I tried briefly with conditional formatting, but could not figure out how to set a conditional based on the cell's background color. I am happy to try a macro-based solution if someone can give me a few pointers.

Comment: What causes the color on the first sheet to change -- does a value change?  If so, then use an event handler that runs a macro whenever the value changes.  Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41783364/5100564.

Comment: I will be changing the background color of the cells in the first sheet manually, by using the format options. So there will be no value change unfortunately.

Comment: In that case, AFAIK there is no way to set up an automated event handler.  You could add a button and click it to call a macro that updates the second sheet.